# Calculate the amount of time for each status

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following table bellow.

The `timeStamp` is the moment that the status began.
There are some rows that don't add new information if status changed (like the second row) and they could be ignored.

I would to calculate (using mysql 5.7) the total amount of time for each status.

```
|      timeStamp      | status |
|------------------------------|
| 2019-12-10 14:00:00 |   1    |  
| 2019-12-10 14:10:00 |   1    | // this row could be ignored
| 2019-12-10 14:00:00 |   2    | // more 24 hours in status 1
| 2019-12-11 14:10:00 |   2    | 
| 2019-12-12 14:00:00 |   1    | // more 24 hours in status 2
| 2019-12-14 14:00:00 |   2    | // more 48 hours in status 1
| 2019-12-16 14:10:00 |   2    |
| 2019-12-17 14:20:00 |   2    | 
| 2019-12-18 14:00:00 |   3    | // more 96 hours in status 2
| 2019-12-19 14:00:00 |   1    | // more 24 hours in status 3
```

I would like to see as result a table like bellow.

```
| status | amount_of_time |
|-------------------------|
|    1   |     72 hours   |
|    2   |     120 hours  |
|    3   |     24 hours   |
```

What complicates this is that the status don't stay in order: is not 1, 2,3.
In the example above it is: 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, so I can't use the `MIN` information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the timestamp of the following row in a subquery and calculate the difference to the timestamp of the current row:

```
select t1.status, timestampdiff(second,
  t1.timeStamp,
  (
    select min(t2.timeStamp)
    from mytable t2
    where t2.timeStamp > t1.timeStamp
  )
) as diff                     
from mytable t1;
```

This will return:

```
| status | diff   |
| ------ | ------ |
| 1      | 600    |
| 1      | 86400  |
| 2      | 600    |
| 2      | 85800  |
| 1      | 172800 |
| 2      | 173400 |
| 2      | 87000  |
| 2      | 85200  |
| 3      | 86400  |
| 1      | NULL   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qMDu64SwXiKqPf25aqkzEX/0)

From here it's just a matter of `GROUP BY` and `SUM`:

```
select status, sum(diff) as duratation_in_seconds
from (
  select t1.status, timestampdiff(second,
    t1.timeStamp,
    (
      select min(t2.timeStamp)
      from mytable t2
      where t2.timeStamp > t1.timeStamp
    )
  ) as diff                     
  from mytable t1
) x
group by status;
```

Result:

```
| status | duratation_in_seconds |
| ------ | --------------------- |
| 1      | 259800                |
| 2      | 432000                |
| 3      | 86400                 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x63HMGCTKAVJUbe5MGqaUF/0)

If you want the time in hours, change the first line to

```
select status, round(sum(diff)/3600) as duratation_in_hours
```

and you will get:

```
| status | duratation_in_hours |
| ------ | ------------------- |
| 1      | 72                  |
| 2      | 120                 |
| 3      | 24                  |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/njsd2cVKiswjQZ3RtGUbHg/0)

You might though want to use `floor()` instead of `round()`. That's not clear from your question.

In MySQL 8 you could use the [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) window function to get the timestamp of the next row:

```
select status, sum(diff) as duratation_in_seconds
from (
  select 
    status,
    timestampdiff(second, timeStamp, lead(timeStamp) over (order by timeStamp)) as diff
  from mytable
) x
group by status;
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgh7nDnwYVnCNJ8un1SNd9/0)